# How to assign a sequential number to ThreadPoolExecutor worker

Tags: python, threadpoolexecutor

assuming the following code example where a list of files getting uploaded, using  ThreadPoolExecutor as executor.

```
    def upload_segments(segment_upload_list):
        def __upload(object_path_pair):
            libera_resource.upload_file(*object_path_pair)
            print("Segment uploaded!")

        with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
            executor.map(__upload, segment_upload_list)
    upload_segments(segment_upload_list)
```

How can I assign a number to the point where I'm in my list in this multithreaded scenario? I want to display something like this in the end:

"Segment 10/4310 uploaded."

I'm aware that the output cannot be sequential here due to the nature of multithreading, but it would at least provide a progress overview. I guess counting the number of threads I've already started would also do the trick here to count the number of segments already uploaded

Thanks in advance

Comment: Even if it's possible, I don't think knowing which one of the `ThreadPoolExecutor`'s `max_workers` threads performed the upload would tell you much about the number of segments already processed. In other words there is no correlation between the thread number and the total number of segments already uploaded.

Comment: But assuming that one thread processes one file, and also assuming that I have 4310 segment in total. If 4310 threads where started it equals 4310 segemnts? Or im wrong here?

Comment: That's not the same thing as assigning a number to a worker. To know the number uploaded so far, you could have a global counter (protected by `Lock`) that each thread incremented when it finished an upload. The value of this counter could be queried as desired to determine how many had been uploaded thus far.

Comment: Can you show this in a pratical example?

Comment: you could create list with pairs `[(0, segment0), (1, segment1), ... ]` - ie. using `list(enumerate(segment_upload_list))` - and use this list with `map()` - and function would have to get these extra value `number = object_path_pair[0]` , `object_path_pair = object_path_pair[1:]`. But problem is that system may run theads in different moments and they may run in random order - and you may get text in random order. - ie. `10/4310` before `2/4310`

Comment: @furas: I think you probably meant "… - and function would have to get these extra values `number = object_path_pair[0]` , `segment_info = object_path_pair[1]`".

Comment: @martineau you are right :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an illustration of how to use a global counter like I suggested in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72250952/how-to-assign-a-sequential-number-to-threadpoolexecutor-worker#comment127649492_72250952). Each upload is being simulated by having each worker thread sleep for a random amount of time.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from time import sleep
import threading
import random


count_lock = threading.Lock()
count = 0

def upload_file(segment):
    global count

    print(f'Uploading segment #{segment}...')
    sleep(random.uniform(1, 5))  # Simulate variable-length upload.
    with count_lock:
        count += 1
        print(f'  {count} of {len(segment_upload_list)} uploaded.')


def upload_segments(segment_upload_list):
    global count

    count = 0
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
        executor.map(upload_file, segment_upload_list)

    print('\nAll segments uploaded!')


segment_upload_list = list(range(1, 11))
upload_segments(segment_upload_list)
```

Sample output. Note how it immediately starts 3 upload task threads, and then starts another one everytime one finishes. This is because of the limit specified when the `ThreadPoolExecutor` was created. As you can see it doesn't really matter which one of the three performed that task as I said in my even earlier [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72250952/how-to-assign-a-sequential-number-to-threadpoolexecutor-worker/72252514#comment127649208_72250952).

```
Uploading segment #1...
Uploading segment #2...
Uploading segment #3...
  1 of 10 uploaded.
Uploading segment #4...
  2 of 10 uploaded.
Uploading segment #5...
  3 of 10 uploaded.
Uploading segment #6...
  4 of 10 uploaded.
Uploading segment #7...
  5 of 10 uploaded.
Uploading segment #8...
  6 of 10 uploaded.
Uploading segment #9...
  7 of 10 uploaded.
Uploading segment #10...
  8 of 10 uploaded.
  9 of 10 uploaded.
  10 of 10 uploaded.

All segments uploaded!
```

Comment: is pool2 nessessary in any way?

Comment: No, it was just something leftover from some code from another answer I once wrote to a different question about having two `ThreadPoolExecutor`s.

Comment: Actually, there was some other unneeded code, so I've removed it also.

Comment: and segment_upload_list = list(range(1, 11)) should be segment_upload_list = list(range(1, len(segment_upload_list))) ???

Comment: Currently I always drop out with: TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object

Comment: My code was is merely a demostration of how to do the overall processing while showing sequential numbers all without assigning individual numbers to the workers — the "segments" are simply integers since the code does not actually do any uploading. You'll have to adapt it to do the real processing you want (which ought to be relatively easy).

Comment: If you want to send the segment number *and* the segment info to each worker, you can do so doing as @furas [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72250952/how-to-assign-a-sequential-number-to-threadpoolexecutor-worker/72252514#comment127650623_72250952) (i.e. use `enumerate` and pass a pair of values in the single argument that gets passed to each worker thread).